# Regex expression for file name with 2 underscores and 3 segments

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need a **regex** expression that will select files with particular file name format from the file list of properties files.
I need to select files with file names with following file format:

```
<app_name>_<app_version>_<environment>.properties
```

- here `<app_name>` can be any alphanumeric with special character `<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>` like `abc123` or `app1-1`
- here `<app_version>` can be any alphanumeric with special character `<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char/float value>` like `abc` or even **float/integer/string** `1.0` or `2` or  abc1
- here `<environment>` can be any alphanumeric with special character `<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>` like `production` or  prod1

Together they are bind with 2 underscore as follows:-

```
<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>_<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char/float value>_<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>.properties
```

The file name always contains 2 underscore `_`, and it can be any string between the underscores .
for examples, following are **valid** file names that can be selected:

```
app1_1.0_prod1.properties
app2_2_prod2.properties
app_vers1_prod.properties
app-1_vers1_prod-2.properties
asd_efg_eee.properties
```

It can be letter or number or special char or combination between them, between the underscore .
Please note that it can be only 2 underscore `_` in the file name.
Anything other than 2 underscore `_` is not a valid file name and will not be selected and the file name should always have these 3 sections separated by 2 underscore `_`
Following are **invalid** file name:

```
abc.properties
abc.123.efg.properties
as_1.efg.ddd.rr.properties
ee_rr.properties
_rr_.properties
```

I tried following regex:

```
[^_]*\\.[^_].properties
```

but not working. Maybe this is wrong. I am not getting the clue of getting this.
Please help me in creating this regex.
Thanks

Comment: Is this in Java or Javascript?

Comment: Using currently in Java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `/^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+\.properties$/` should meet your requirements:

```js
const tests = [
  'app1_1.0_prod1.properties',
  'app2_2_prod2.properties',
  'app_vers1_prod.properties',
  'asd_efg_eee.properties',
  'abc.properties',
  'abc.123.efg.properties',
  'as_1.efg.ddd.rr.properties',
  'ee_rr.properties',
  '_rr_.properties'
];

tests.forEach(test => { 
  console.log(test, /^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+\.properties$/.test(test)); 
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `/^([^_]+_){2}[^_]+\.properties$/`

If you want to tighten down on the use of `.`, then I think you want

```
/^[^_.]+_([^_.]+|\d+(\.\d+)?)_[^_.]+\.properties$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, since each section can include basically any character except an underscore: `/[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]\.properties/`