# Python: Regex to extract strings from a file name that follows a specific pattern

Tags: python

I have file name in the below format:

```
<IndentNo>_<DocType>_<DocName>_<Date>_<Version>.<Extension>
An Example: 
1000023456_SOTR_FILE23_21102020_V1.pdf
```

I want to retrieve `<IndentNo>`,`<DocType>`,`<DocName>` separately. I am not well conversant with Regex thus seeking help. Ideally my code snippet should be as follows:

```
IndentNo, DocType, DocName = re.findall('regex pattern', file_name,re.I)[0],\
                             re.findall('regex pattern', file_name,re.I)[1],\
                             re.findall('regex pattern', file_name,re.I)[2]
IndentNo, DocType, DocName = '1000023456','SOTR','FILE23'
```

I am looking for the suitable `regex pattern` for each category of string.
Following [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750596/regex-expression-for-file-name-with-2-underscores-and-3-segments), I have no luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract part(s) of string using regex, you can use groups

```
filename = '1000023456_SOTR_FILE23_21102020_V1.pdf'
match = re.match('(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.(.*)', filename)
no, type, name, date, ver, ext = match.groups()
```

Here:

`.*` is any string;

`(.*)` is a group containing any string;

`\.` will match just dot, backslash is used to escape the dot because by default it has special meaning in regex (it means any char)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
text = "<IndentNo>_<DocType>_<DocName>_<Date>_<Version>.<Extension>"
re.split("_|\.",text)
```

Which returns:

```
['<IndentNo>', '<DocType>', '<DocName>', '<Date>', '<Version>', '<Extension>']
```

If you're confident that all those elements will be present, then this could be read into a series of variables using the syntax:

```
indent, doctype, docname, date, version, extension = re.split("_|\.",text)
```